# How to have LINQ do a CAST() in SQL Server?

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a table in SQL Server with an entry that came from:

```
INSERT INTO table(data) VALUES CAST(getdate() AS BINARY(8))
```

I would like to do a LINQ query that will perform:

```
SELECT CAST(data AS DATETIME) FROM table
```

How can I accomplish this?

The datetime is stored as binary(8) in SQL Server for reasons beyond my control, and I need to retrieve the datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a model defined function to implement the CAST

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

See here for an analogous example:
[Convert String to Int in EF 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754218/convert-string-to-int-in-ef-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a `sql_variant` column.

`sql_variant` is not supported in LINQ to SQL / EF, hence a trick is needed to get the query generated with a `CAST(column as your_desired_type)` otherwise LINQ to SQL will throw an exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type '%your desired type%'`.

So, first define the column in your model with type `object` (instead of e.g. `string`)

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table]
public class CompanyDimensionValue
{
  // type "object" + private setter because Linq to SQL cannot map sql_variant
  [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column]
  public object Code { get; private set; }
}
```

and secondly add a `System.Convert.ToString()` to the query:

```
from v in table select
  System.Convert.ToString(v.Code) // <- this generates a CAST(... as nvarchar...)
```