# Int.Parse in Linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ expression. I want calculate the sum of numeric values in an `nvarchar` field. I'm using following code to do this, but I get an error when I try to run this.

```
var m = new MaterialModelContainer();

var list = 
    (from x in
        (
            from inv in m.INVs
            join l in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals l.MESC
            join o in m.OUTs on inv.MESC equals o.MESC
            join t in m.TRANs on inv.MESC equals t.MESC
            where t.TYPE == "60"
            select new
            {
                l.MESC,
                l.LINE_NO,
                l.UNIT_LINE,
                Description = l.DES + " " + l.PART_NO,
                inv.NEW_QTY,
                o.PJ,
                o.DATE,
                o.QTY,
                o.QTY_REC,
                TranQty = t.QTY,
                tranDate = t.DATE
            }
        )
        group x by
            new
            {
                x.MESC,
                x.LINE_NO,
                x.UNIT_LINE,
                x.Description,
                x.NEW_QTY,
                x.PJ,
                x.DATE,
                x.QTY,
                x.QTY_REC
            }
        into g
        select new
        {
            QTY_Consum_1 = g.Where(c => int.Parse(c.tranDate) >= cuDate && int.Parse(c.tranDate) <= endDate).Sum(d => int.Parse(d.TranQty))
        }
    ).ToList();
```

**Error Description:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression

How can I solve this problem and write this code better than this?

I changed the code to this:

```
select new
{
    QTY_Consum_1 = g.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.tranDate) >= cuDate && SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.tranDate) <= endDate).Sum(d => SqlFunctions.StringConvert(d.TranQty)),
   g.Key.MESC
}
).ToList();
```

but got this error:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you: [Convert string to int in EF 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754218/convert-string-to-int-in-ef-4-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use int.parse in `where`.  You can rewrite your query like this:

```
var list = (from x in
                (
                    from inv in m.INVs
                    join l in m.LIBs on inv.MESC equals l.MESC
                    join o in m.OUTs on inv.MESC equals o.MESC
                    join t in m.TRANs on inv.MESC equals t.MESC
                    where t.TYPE == "60" && t.QTY!=""
                    select new
                       {
                           l.MESC,
                           l.LINE_NO,
                           l.UNIT_LINE,
                           Description = l.DES + " " + l.PART_NO,
                           inv.NEW_QTY,
                           o.PJ,
                           o.DATE,
                           o.QTY,
                           o.QTY_REC,
                           TranQty = t.QTY,
                           tranDate = t.DATE

                      }
                ).ToList()
            group x by
                new
                    {
                        x.MESC,
                        x.LINE_NO,
                        x.UNIT_LINE,
                        x.Description,
                        x.NEW_QTY,
                        x.PJ,
                        x.DATE,
                        x.QTY,
                        x.QTY_REC
                    }
            into g
            select new
                {
                    QTY_Consum_1 = g.Where(c => int.Parse(c.tranDate) >= cuDate && int.Parse(c.tranDate) <= endDate).Sum(d => int.Parse(d.TranQty)),
                    g.Key.MESC
                }
           ).ToList();
```

Call `.ToList()` method, then use `int.Parse(variable)`.

Have a nice day.

Comment: but the where clause will be executed outside the database!

Comment: Better to use `AsEnumerable` to avoid creating the intermediate list.

Answer (score 20):

**EF 5:**

Instead of `int.Parse` use `Convert.ToInt32`. Entity Framework will generate proper `CAST` functions in SQL.

**EF 6:**

*Short answer:*

```
youEntity.Where(c=>SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)c.INTFIELD).Trim() == STRINGVALUE)
```

*Long answer:*

in EF 6 you have to convert numeric value to string with [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.stringconvert(v=vs.113).aspx). but it has a problem. It will add unnecessary spaces to the result. so the comparison will fail. That's why I have put `Trim()` there. I have tested it with EF 6.1.1.

Comment: Can someone confirm this? For me this does not work (EF 6.1.0)

Comment: The question is about parsing string to int, not vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework can't translate that type of conversion to SQL.

Is there any chance you could alter your data structure to use proper data types such as actual `DateTime` types? For large data volumes conversions like that will affect performance.

I would recommend either changing your data model types to avoid these conversions, or **if the amount of data will always be small**, then get the data first, and later use Linq to Objects.

Answer (score 4):

In your where clause, you can't call `int.Parse`. Entity Framework doesn't know how to convert that to SQL. Consider revising your `Where`.

Answer (score 3):

Replace all your `int.Parse` by `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(variable)`. There's no function to convert String to Int. You should try to do the inverse and convert your Int to String with StringConvert.

The SqlFunctions utilities will be able to translate the command in SQL command.

Comment: Won't that do the opposite, and convert numbers to strings?

Comment: i change int.parse to SqlFunctions.StringConvert(variable) but i get error, i edit question. please help me. thanks

Comment: @PabloRomea you're right. I missed that! But it doesnt seems to have a function to convert string to int. For now, i would inverse the clause by converting your Int to String with StringConvert

Comment: @M.B the value passed to StringConvert must be `Double` or `Decimal`. You will need to cast your variable to one of these types.

Comment: type  tranDate  is string( in sql is nvarchar)

Comment: @Alexandre Right, it doesn't unfortunately. The problem with converting to strings is that depending on what data it is the > and < comparisons may render incorrect results.

Comment: @M.B is there a reason why tranDate is a string and storing numbers that seem to actually represent dates?

Comment: @M.B like Pablo said, i think that firstly, you have a problem with how your data are stored in your database. And about converting string to int, it's seems impossible. I didnt find any doc to help. The only solution would be to convert your Int to String but you can have a few problems with some comparaisons like Pablo said above

Comment: The database does not belong to me And I can only run queries on it I'm.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a lot, I recommend [CodeFirstStoreFunctions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions/).

Step0 -> CodeFirstStoreFunctions nuget install

Step1-> Create a simple sql scalar functions

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ToInt32](@Value VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS INT
 AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN CONVERT(INT, (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@Value) = 1 THEN @Value ELSE 
 '0' END))
 END
```

Step2 -> add in OnModelCreating

```
mb.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", typeof(SqlHelper)));
```

Step3 -> build in the SqlHelper class

```
[DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "ToInt32")]
public static int ToInt32(string value) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

Result -> [image]

Answer (score -1):

When you need to make sure a CLR method can be used in LINQ to Entities you'd better consult this source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456828(v=vs.100).aspx.

Not a fast reading, it'd take time, but here's the answer to your question (and many more like it).

Answer (score -2):

There is a badly built database, which I cannot edit, but have to use it.

I use this in Linq-To-Sql and it works.

First cast the string to object, then cast it to int.

```
 from s in db.Students
 select new
 {
     s.Name,
     s.Surname,
     Birthday = new DateTime((int)(object)(s.dateStr.Substring(0, 4)),
                             (int)(object)(s.dateStr.Substring(4, 2)),
                             (int)(object)(s.dateStr.Substring(6, 2))),
 }
```