# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method when attempting to parse a column for inequality comparisons

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following code in my page:

```
var myVar= Entity.SetName
                 .Where(p => int.Parse(p.ID) >= start &&
                  int.Parse(p.ID) <= end);
```

start and end are int, but *p.ID* is string. So i should convert *p.ID* to int. But i get following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Where is the problem??

Comment: Redesign your DB and make `ID` as integer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan , I think, your suggestion is the best solution...

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities) can help you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*First, I would highly recommend to check your database design, whether there is a really good reason for `ID` to be a `string`. I would consider changing the `ID` DB type to `int` and you will get rid of this problem with converting*.

The error you get means, that EF does not know how to convert the method `Int32.Parse()` to SQL. 
Basically you have two options how to deal with that:

Do the comparison outside the linq to entities:

```
var myVar= Entity.SetName.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where(p => int.Parse(p.ID) >= start &&
                  int.Parse(p.ID) <= end);
```

But this is **not recommended**, because you are reading whole result set from DB, before applying the `where` condition.

Or make **custom model defined function** as described in this post on SO:

[Convert String to Int in EF 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754218/convert-string-to-int-in-ef-4-0)
or
[Entity Framework: Where do I extend the CSDL/MSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612827/entity-framework-where-do-i-extend-the-csdl-msl/5613642#5613642)

Comment: How i can add xml part of custom model defined function?

Comment: You have to manually edit your `.edmx` file and add it to the `CSDL` part. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456812%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

First try to convert to `int` then pass that variable name

```
int catgry = Convert.ToInt32(customercategory.OWNERSHIP_TYPE);
var customerCateg = (from d in _db.tbl_SIL_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_MST
    .Where(d => d.CAT_ID == catgry) select d.CAT_TYPE).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520141/861716). Again, this doesn't answer the question how to convert p.ID where p is a range variable.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure the original answer was the best one available at the time, it is quite old. As noted in that answer, the problem is that Entity Framework does not support translation of `int.Parse()`. It does, however, support `Convert.ToInt32()` which can be used instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410610/13425903).

Changing the sample code from this:

```cs
var myVar= Entity.SetName
                 .Where(p => int.Parse(p.ID) >= start &&
                  int.Parse(p.ID) <= end);
```

To this:

```cs
var myVar= Entity.SetName
                 .Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.ID) >= start &&
                  Convert.ToInt32(p.ID) <= end);
```

Should produce the correct T-SQL without any errors.

Note that this may not be supported with all Entity Framework versions. I was not able to find anything on when this capability was first introduced with a quick search, but do know similar types of conversions can vary in how they need to be implemented across versions and especially across EF and EF Core.

This should probably be a comment on the accepted answer, but I can't make those, and this still pops up as a top result in Google in spite of its age, so I'm throwing it in here in case it helps someone else encountering a similar issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35336997)

Comment: [bolt-io](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5503832/bolt-io) could you please expand on how this fails to answer the question? OP asked about LINQ to Entities not supporting int.Parse(). I stated it is not supported, but Convert.ToInt32() is and can be used instead. I had the same question as OP and this was indeed the answer for me. What clarification do you believe is needed from the asker?

Comment: Hi [Cristian Sanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13425903/cristian-sanchez), thanks for your contribution and drive to make StackOverflow a better place. Although, as stated by yourself, this feels like it should be a comment rather than an answer. Moreover, the answer posted just confirms the correct usage that had already been identified by another answer, which you linked. If you wish to improve on someone else's answer and cannot comment, please expand with code samples and a more rounded definition as the answer you linked in yours may be deleted in the future and the context lost.

Comment: [bolt-io](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5503832/bolt-io), thanks for the feedback. You have a point about context potentially being lost in the future. I've expanded my answer as suggested. It's true my answer rephrases one from another question, but I don't think that invalidates it. Others, like myself, are likely still running into this question years later. If anything, these related questions might be candidates for consolidation as duplicates. If I could, I would've made a comment on the accepted answer pointing to the updated solution. Still, I felt it was worth writing up an answer.

Comment: That's a much better answer  Thank you for updating it!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void LoadDetail(int id)
    {
        var sp = from category in db.ProductCategories
                 join product in db.Products on category.ProductCategoryID equals product.ProductCategoryID
                 where id == int.Parse(category.ProductCategoryID)
                 select new
                 {
                     product.ProductID,
                     product.ProductName,
                     product.ProductCode,
                     product.Deception,
                     category.CategoryName,
                     product.Quanrity,
                     product.Price
                 };
        DGVDetail.DataSource = sp.ToList();//help: Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
    }

    private void DGVMaster_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;
        LoadDetail(index + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Convert string to int, you have to make it Enumerable, then you can make sort or anything you like

```
  var list = db.UserEntriesTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {

             Name = x.Name,

             Roll = Convert.ToInt32(x.Roll),

             Mobile = x.Mobile

        }).OrderBy(x => x.Roll).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int nb = EE.Stagaire.Join(EE.Filiere, S => S.IdFiliere, F => F.IdFiliere, (S, F) => new
        {
            ID = S.Id,
            Name = S.Nom,
            Prénon = S.Prenon,
            Email = S.Email,
            MoteDePass = S.MoteDePass,
            Filiere = F.Filiere1,
        }).Where(S => S.ID.ToString() == r.ToString()).Take(1).Count();
        if (nb != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("find it");

        }
```

//You can do that if you have to data type is integer

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not efficient, you should be able to load all rows, and then use LINQ to Objects:

```
var myVar= Entity.SetName.ToList()
                 .Where(p => int.Parse(p.ID) >= start &&
                  int.Parse(p.ID) <= end);
```

Comment: Performance!!! with `Entity.SetName.ToList()` If you have 1M entries, then you read them all before u select them that satisfy the `Where` criteria.

Comment: he already mentioned "its not efficient". may be for this very specific case he will only have 100s of records. so where is the harm? I dont udnerstand how people down vote answers unless it is not warning and suggesting the "bad" way!