# How to use c# to perform summing data with type conversion from SQL using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I was trying to sum up a column of type `nvarchar(7)` that I need to first convert data to `decimal(18, 7)`.

I used this LINQ query:

```
var Data = queryBase.Select(q => new { totalVol = q.Collection.Sum(c => Convert.ToDecimal(c.Volume) }).FirstOrDefault();
```

However I got an exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(System.String)' method...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method when attempting to parse a column for inequality comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558837/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-int32-parsesystem-string-meth)

Comment: Adding D Staney's answer below, just convert the values to Decimal before this line (and store in new List). It requires you to make a new List but will solve your problem. However, if you're 100% sure all the Volumes can be converted without null or empty values, just use `q.Collection.Sum(c => (decimal) c.Volume)`

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty clear.  EF is not programmed to convert the `Convert.ToDecimal` call to SQL.

Some options:

- Write the equivalent SQL manually and call it using `ExecuteQuery`
- Create a view on top of your data that converts the strings to numbers and query that.
- Pull all of the data into memory and to the conversion/summation in Linq-to-Objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cast<double>` before doing the `Sum` This will throw an exception if the database can't convert the string

```
var Data = 
    queryBase.Select(q => 
       new 
       { 
          totalVol = q.Collection
                      .Select(c => c.Volume)
                      .Cast<double>()
                      .Sum()   
       }
     ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nice trick, didn't know EF supports something like this until now! +1

Answer (score 0):

As the Convert.ToDecimal must be converted to SQL, EF doesn't know how to do it.

So, do a `queryBase.ToList()` first (this will execute the SQL and all the data is in memory, as objects).

To minimize the size of the retrieved data do: `queryBase.Select(/*here filter the string field*/).ToList().`

Then, do the sum, using `Convert` or `Decimal.Parse`

Comment: This is will load the entire collection into memory.  I doubt that that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @DavidL, yes, if there are lots of data could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

try some like this:

```
var Data = queryBase.Select(c =>c.Volume).AsEnumerable().Sum(d => Convert.ToDecimal(d.Volume));
```

Comment: What is there that suggests that the OP is using nullable ints?  They are almost certainly mapping to a string.