# How can apply TryParse on multiple propertied with fluent LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object. The object looks like so

```
public class GenericRecord
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
    public float ConvertedCol1 { get; set; }
    public float ConvertedCol3 { get; set; }
    public float ConvertedCol3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use fluent LINQ to parse the the `Col1`,`Col2`, and `Col3` properties and then sum them.

I would like to do something like this

```
IEnumerable<GenericRecord> records = ...;
var summaries = records.Select(x => new GenericRecord 
{
   float.TryParse(x.Col1, out ConvertedCol1),
   float.TryParse(x.Col2, out ConvertedCol2),
   float.TryParse(x.Col3, out ConvertedCol3),
   GroupName => x.GroupName
}).GroupBy(x => x.GroupName)
.Select(x => new {
   GroupName = x.Key,
   Total1 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol1),
   Total2 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol2),
   Total3 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol3),
   Count = x.Count()
}).ToList();
```

However, that `float.TryParse` syntaxt in linq does not work.

How can I parse multiple columns using Fluent LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put processing in a method:

```
private static GenericRecord ConvertGenericRecord(GenericRecord x) {
    float c1, c2, c3;
    float.TryParse(x.Col1, out c1);
    float.TryParse(x.Col2, out c2);
    float.TryParse(x.Col3, out c3);
    return new GenericRecord {
        ConvertedCol1 = c1;
        ConvertedCol2 = c2;
        ConvertedCol3 = c3;
        GroupName = x.GroupName
    };
}
```

Use the method as follows:

```
var summaries = records
    .Select(ConvertGenericRecord)
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupName)
    .Select(x => new {
        GroupName = x.Key,
        Total1 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol1),
        Total2 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol2),
        Total3 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol3),
        Count = x.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Calls to `TryParse` wouldn't work in EF or LINQ2SQL. If you are reading from DB, add `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()` before invoking `ConvertGenericRecord`.

If the conversion must take place on the DB side, replace `TryParse` with `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(...)` ([detailed Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410610/335858)).

Answer (score 1):

You cant use an object initializer syntax that way. It needs the name of the property on the left hand side, not with a reference.

Perhaps `GenericRecord` can have a constructor and do the conversion for you or have the properties convert it for you.

Comment: The `records` object is populated from a database. The only other way I can convert it is by adding a function to that object which will handle the tryparse for me. However, I won't be able to use my custom function in LINQ to sum the parsed data, Is there another way to do this beside using constructors?

Answer (score 0):

Operations are not supported within an object initilizer, if you look at a object initiliser for your Generic Record class:

```
var record = new GenericRecord
{
    GroupName = "Group",
    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
    Col1 = "Col1",
    Col2 = "Col2",
    Col3 = "Col3",
};
```

It may be obvious as to what you issue may be, if I were you I would push this functionality into the constructor of Generic Record:

```
public GenericRecord(string col1, string col2, string col3, string groupName)
{
   float convertedVal1;
   if (float.TryParse(col1, out convertedVal1))
   {
      ConvertedCol1 = convertedVal1;
   }
}
```

now your Linq statement will be much easier:

```
var summaries = records.Select(x => new GenericRecord(x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3, x.GroupName))
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupName)
            .Select(x => new {
                GroupName = x.Key,
                Total1 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol1),
                Total2 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol2),
                Total3 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol3),
                Count = x.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Edit:
Another possible solution to this, if you don't mind the non-safe casting is to use float.Parse:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var summaries = records.Select(x => new GenericRecord
            {
                ConvertedCol1 = float.Parse(x.Col1),
                ConvertedCol2 = float.Parse(x.Col2),
                ConvertedCol3 = float.Parse(x.Col3),
                GroupName = x.GroupName
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.GroupName)
            .Select(x => new {
                GroupName = x.Key,
                Total1 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol1),
                Total2 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol2),
                Total3 = x.Sum(y => y.ConvertedCol3),
                Count = x.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Hope this helps