# OrderBy on a Nullable<int> with a default value in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

We are migrating some code to use Entity Framework and have a query that is trying to sort on a Nullable field and provides a default sort value is the value is null using the [Nullable.GetValueOrDefault(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx) function.

However, upon execution it returns the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetValueOrDefault(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The query looks like:

```
int magicDefaultSortValue = 250;
var query = context.MyTable.OrderBy(t => t.MyNullableSortColumn
                                          .GetValueOrDefault(magicDefaultSortValue));
```

From [this answer I can see that there is a way to provide "translations" within your EDMX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met/5971677#5971677). Could we write a similar translation for this coalescing function?

NOTE: When I tried, the `??` coalescing operator instead of GetValueOrDefault in the query it does work. So perhaps whatever makes that work could be leveraged?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you found your answer.  When you use `??`, EF generates SQL using a `CASE` to select your sort value if the value is `null`, and then sorts on that.

```
MyTable.OrderBy (t => t.MyNullableSortColumn ?? magicDefaultSortValue).ToArray();
```

will generate the following sql:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE p__linq__0 Int = 250
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
[Project1].[MyColumn1] AS [MyColumn1], 
[Project1].[MyNullableSortColumn] AS [MyNullableSortColumn]
FROM ( SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[MyNullableSortColumn] IS NULL) THEN @p__linq__0 ELSE [Extent1].[MyNullableSortColumn] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[MyColumn1] AS [MyColumn1], 
    [Extent1].[MyNullableSortColumn] AS [MyNullableSortColumn]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

As an aside, I would recommend getting [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) which will let you work with your EF models and view the sql being generated.  Also, it is helpful to know about the [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) class and [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) class as they provide access to several useful functions.

Comment: Thanks! However, after I found the `??` to work I was hoping not to have to edit my existing queries (written against a LINQ To SQL context) that were already using GetValueOrDefault().