# LINQ to Entities string to double conversion

Tags: entity-framework-4

I'm working for the first time with LINQ to Entities.

My data store has a string field that depending on certain other fields is often an integer.  I cannot change the structure of this database.

The table in question in the EF is masterdatas.

I am attempting to create the sum for these records in the varvalue field based on a grouping based on the varname field as such:

```
var varsum = from md in context.masterdatas
             where md.imparcid == SelectedDataSet.imparcid && md.varname == t.VarName
             group md by md.varname into g
             select new { varname = g.Key, SummedAmt = g.Sum(md => Convert.ToDouble(md.varvalue)) };
```

I get an error LINQ to Entities does not recognize method Double ToDouble(system string).

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met) SO question, I added a DefiningExpression to my EDMX model, and defined the function in a partial class of my datamodel and used this code:

```
var varsum = from md in context.masterdatas
             where md.imparcid == SelectedDataSet.imparcid && md.varname == t.VarName
             group md by md.varname into g
             select new { varname = g.Key, SummedAmt = g.Sum(md => context.ParseDouble(md.varvalue)) };
```

Now I'm getting an error that the ParseDouble function cannot be translated into a LINQ to entities store expression.

All I'm really trying to do is to get this SQL statement to run:

```
SELECT [varname]
      ,[vartype]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN Isnumeric([varvalue])=1 THEN cast([varvalue] as float) Else 0 END)
  FROM [masterdata]
  Group by varname, imparcid, vartype
  Having imparcid=25 AND varname = 'S2CMT8B'
```

I'm at a loss about the best way to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

On the last line of your LINQ query you need to call the **static** `ParseDouble` method on your context **class**, not the `context` instance:

```cs
// ...
select new { varname = g.Key, SummedAmt = g.Sum(md =>
    MyContextClass.ParseDouble(md.varvalue)) };
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//  NOT the context instance, just the class name because ParseDouble is static
```

I believe only in that case the `EdmFunction` attribute is handled by EF, otherwise it tries to call the method like an ordinary .NET method which throws the exception.

**Edit**

It's also important that you specify the correct model namespace in the `EdmFunction` attribute. If your EDMX looks like this...

```xml
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="MyDBModel" Alias="Self"
      xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">

    <!-- etc. -->

    <Function Name="ParseDouble" ReturnType="Edm.Double">
      <Parameter Name="stringvalue" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        cast(stringvalue as Edm.Double)
      </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>

  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

... your must specify the namespace of the schema `MyDBModel` as first parameter of the `EdmFunctionAttribute`:

```cs
[EdmFunction("MyDBModel", "ParseDouble")]
public static double ParseDouble(string stringvalue)
{
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise `ParseDouble` will be treated as a normal .NET method and result in the exception that it can't be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Thanks Slauma, but after making this change, I'm still getting the error "The specified method 'Double ParseDouble(System.String) on the type 'IFR_Full.IFREntities' (i.e MyContextClass) cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression when I step through the code and the linq to entities statement executes.

Comment: @DeeDub84: Can you check my Edit section above? Having the wrong namespace specified leads to exactly your exception.