# Cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am relatively new to LINQ-to-Entities, but use LINQ-to-SQL a lot.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Entity Framework 6 and MVC 5.

The biggest difference between the two is that Linq2SQL has the ability to perform conversions inside the `SELECT` query itself whereas LINQ2Entities is not as forgiving and must have the right conversion in place before executing the LINQ query. Therefore, I am getting the error:

> The specified method 'System.Decimal ConvertToDecimal(Byte)' on the type 'BillYeagerDB.EdmxExtensionMethods' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.

After doing much research, especially on Stack Overflow with this question, I discovered a link ([LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met)), but he was working with the `ObjectContext` and I am working with the `DbContext`.

I'm also sure it will work for me, but I think I'm just designing the extension method incorrectly (which gives me the above error). Note that this specific issue is with the `AvgRating` variable in the LINQ query. Once I can get this to work, I can do the same type of fixing for any other conversions. Note that `AvgRating` is defined as type `Decimal` and `a.Rating.RatingValue` is defined as type `Byte`.

If somebody can straighten me out on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code. I'm trying to use the following query, which I know won't work (as mentioned before) because of the conversion issue.

**Original LINQ Query:**

```
namespace BillYeagerDB
{
    public class BillYeagerDB
    {
        public async Task<List<RestaurantList>> GetRestaurantListAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using (BillYeagerEntities DbContext = new BillYeagerEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    var restaurants = await DbContext.Restaurants.GroupBy(g => g).Select(s =>
                        new RestaurantList()
                        {
                            Name = s.Key.Name,
                            City = s.Key.City,
                            Phone = s.Key.Phone,
                            AvgRating = s.Average(a => Convert.ToDecimal(a.Rating.RatingValue)),
                            NbrOfPeopleRating = s.Distinct().Count(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.RatingId)),
                            Id = s.Key.Id
                        }).ToListAsync();

                    return restaurants;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update I needed to do to my EDMX file**

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="BillYeagerModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <Function Name="ParseDecimal" ReturnType="Edm.Decimal"> 
            <Parameter Name="bytevalue" Type="Edm.Byte" /> 
            <DefiningExpression> 
                cast(bytevalue as Edm.Decimal)
            </DefiningExpression> 
        </Function>
```

**C# extension method which is a class on the root of my project - not inside my EDMX**

```
namespace BillYeagerDB
{
    public partial class EdmxExtensionMethods : DbContext
    {
        [DbFunctionAttribute("BillYeagerDB", "ParseDecimal")]
        public static Decimal ParseDecimal(byte bytevalue)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(bytevalue);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated Linq query - note no design time compile errors and project compiles successfully**

```
namespace BillYeagerDB
{
    public class BillYeagerDB
    {
        public async Task<List<RestaurantList>> GetRestaurantListAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                using (BillYeagerEntities DbContext = new BillYeagerEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    var restaurants = await DbContext.Restaurants.GroupBy(g => g).Select(s =>
                        new RestaurantList()
                        {
                            Name = s.Key.Name,
                            City = s.Key.City,
                            Phone = s.Key.Phone,
                            AvgRating = s.Average(a => EdmxExtensionMethods.ConvertToDecimal(a.Rating.RatingValue)),
                            NbrOfPeopleRating = s.Distinct().Count(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.RatingId)),
                            Id = s.Key.Id
                        }).ToListAsync();

                    return restaurants;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to cast your byte to a different type directly in the query, without the use of a custom method. Perhaps not straight to double (I'm not sure), but if not, an intermediate conversion should work, perhaps byte -> int -> double.

Comment: Your own solution also works for me; you should post it as an answer and accept it so we can vote it up!

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a little late to the party but for anyone doing a Google search:

I had this problem and it turns out the class the DbFunctionAttribute is on has to have the same namespace as the edmx schema.

So in this case either change the edmx schema namespace to BillYeagerDB,
or change the EdmxExtensionMethods namespace to BillYeagerModel

Answer (score -1):

try to rewrite your select method to this:

```
var restaurants = await DbContext.Restaurants.GroupBy(g => g).ToListAsync();
return restaurants.Select(s =>
  new RestaurantList()
  {
    Name = s.Key.Name,
    City = s.Key.City,
    Phone = s.Key.Phone,
    AvgRating = s.Average(a => Convert.ToDecimal(a.Rating.RatingValue)),
    NbrOfPeopleRating = s.Distinct().Count(c => Convert.ToBoolean(c.RatingId)),
    Id = s.Key.Id
  });
```

Comment: -1 because this forces retrieval of data that isn't interesting, and will throw exceptions if lazy loading is disabled.

Comment: What kind of uninteresting data will be fetched from DB in this case? And what another way you know to avoid EF restrictions about calling "untraslated" .NET methods? Linq2Sql?

Comment: All restaurant data that isn't projected will still be retrieved. Separate queries will be used to retrieve `a.Rating` for each restaurant (or an exception if any restaurant does not have a rating, or as mentioned if lazy loading is disabled). As for another way, see my comment on the question.

Comment: Dmytro, that's the original query I had which caused this entire issue. Linq2Entities can't do an inline conversion like Linq2SQL which causes the "Cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression" error. I've read a lot pof post on this, but I think I am missing something in the "Update I needed to do to my EDMX file" or the "C# extension method" I wrote. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: hvd, restaurant data will not be retrieved because the query in its original form causes the "Cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression".

Comment: @sagesky36 It was a small portion of sarcasm ). Because "old and deprecated" Linq2Sql correctly supports transformations in Select method, but "new and clean" EF doesn't. Because EF tries to convert all data from linq query into SQL.

Comment: @sagesky36 The point of this answer is the `ToListAsync()`. This retrieves *all* restaurant data from the server. Then, on the client, it projects it into a `RestaurantList`. It's not what I think you should do, but it's not what you have in your question, and does avoid the exception you're getting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I'm getting anywhere here closer to a resolution. What I need is an actual code snippet of what I need to do.