# Linq To Entity string to int conversion in order by

Tags: c#, linq, casting, linq-to-entities

There is a table in our database the stores year and month, each being a char. The existing Linq to Entity query looks like this:

```
from mc in repository.table.AsQueryable()
orderby mc.Year descending, mc.Month descending
select mc).FirstOrDefault()
```

The issue with this is that it is ordering by string and not int, leading to the incorrect row being returned from the query.  I have tried to convert the year and month to int and datetime, both throwing an error saying:

**"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."**

```
(from mc in repository.table.AsQueryable()
 orderby mc.Year descending, Convert.ToDateTime(mc.Month) descending
 select mc).FirstOrDefault()
```

OR

**"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."**

```
(from mc in repository.table.AsQueryable()
 orderby mc.Year descending, Convert.ToInt32(mc.Month) descending
 select mc).FirstOrDefault();
```

As you can see, I cannot cast the month and year into INTs first because it is using the data from the table, not external data.

PS: I do not have the authority to change the tables to make the two columns INTs.

Anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at the SqlFunctions class, most notably about the [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which can be used with Entity Framework (with no exceptions), and will convert strings into the dates for you to be properly ordered by.

Answer (score 0):

As @IronMan84 noticed solution below works only if you have `.edmx` file.

1. Add the following xml to your .edmx file. (Just do a ‘Find in Files’ in Visual Studio `</Schema>` and place it before this node):

   `<Function Name="IntParse" ReturnType="Edm.Int32">
     <Parameter Name="stringvalue" Type="Edm.String" />
     <DefiningExpression>
       cast(stringvalue as Edm.Int32)
     </DefiningExpression>
   </Function>`
2. Add the following static function to your auto-generated Entity Framework class file:

   `public partial class YourObjectContext
   {
       [EdmFunction("YourModel", "IntParse")]
       public static double IntParse(string val)
       {
           return int.Parse(val);
       }
   }`
3. You are ready to go, just add the new function to your LINQ Query:

   `from mc in repository.table.AsQueryable()
   orderby YourObjectContext.IntParse(mc.Year) descending, YourObjectContext.IntParse(mc.Month) descending
   select mc).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: -1. This answer assumes that he is using an .edmx file, which is not always generated when one is using EF. Code-First, for example, doesn't generate one.

Comment: @IronMan84 It says `PS: I do not have the authority to change the tables to make the two columns INTs.` so I suggested it's about Database first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
(from mc in repository.table.AsQueryable() orderby ((int)mc.Year) descending, ((int)mc.Month) descending select mc).FirstOrDefault();
```