# Orderby string but that values are numbers (double)

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort a `(JamMulai)` that are string but the value are numbers. I'd like `(JamMulai)` to sort numerically

my query:

```
var query = from j in db.JadwalKuliah
            orderby j.JamMulai
            select j
```

and `j.JamMulai` value is like `{ "13", "12,3", "7", "15", "10,3"};`

output:

> (10,3), (12,3), 13, 15, 7

I'd like:

> 7, (10,3), (12,3), 13, 15

I'm trying to convert to double :

```
var query = from j in db.JadwalKuliah
            orderby Convert.ToDouble(j.JamMulai)
            select j
```

but the error is:

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Comment: You are using { "13", "12,3", "7", "15", "10,3"}; as j.JamMulai value is it a typo or the value is like that only because it is having "12,3" and "10,3" which will be treated a string eventhough you convert or Parse

Comment: it's not a typo, the value of JamMulai in table is like that

Answer (score 2):

Use `parse` instead of convert

```
    var numbers = new string[]{ "13", "12,3", "7", "15", "10,3"};

    var sortedNumbers = numbers.
        Select(number => double.Parse(number)).
        OrderBy(number => number).ToArray();
```

Comment: it's still not working when i was started the project. that error is: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Try looking into this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971521/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-parsesystem-string-met

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your query is being translated into SQL and run on the database, and Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate `Double ToDouble(System.String)` into valid SQL code, you can load the data into memory and then perform orderby:-

```
var query = db.JadwalKuliah.ToList()
              .OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x))
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi, how can I orderBy a Double for any language? I'm having problem with english and portuguese languages.