# String to int conversion in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a task to get data from database and draw a diagram based on it. The problem is the data that I need is stored as string (but it should be decimal, why they did it is a mystery and they are not going to make it decimal and that is for sure).
Here is the LINQ query that I write:

```
from SPEKTR in db.SPEKTR
               where
               Convert.ToInt32(SPEKTR.RF) > 88 &&
               Convert.ToInt32(SPEKTR.RF) < 90
               select SPEKTR;
```

And this is the error that I get

> {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression."}

Are there any options to convert that string?

Comment: My proposed duplicate is one because [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,069d595792a157df) calls `int.Parse`.

Comment: If the table isn't too big, you can load data into memory using `AsEnumerable()` and then use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter just a remark : the "duplicate" is about converting the "comparison parameters", not converting the db fields... Which will need a slightly different answer...

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov data is way too big but SQL server is strong.

Comment: @JavidYagubali: i just added a comment why i've closed it as duplicate even if the other question asks for `int.Parse` instead of `System.Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: yes, good point. But the accepted answer explains both.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I read almost all questions about type conversion, none of them had the answer to this question. I think this problem is somehow different, f.y.i., I'm just a noob in microsoft related technologies

Comment: This answer has a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971677/468973

Comment: I think I got the point, thank you for your effort and patience!

Comment: @Magnus that answer didn't help, i used code-first approach, I don't have any *.edmx file

Comment: i used this code to reproduce your problem:

List<string> list = new List<string> {"1.5","2.5","3.1","4.2" };

            var a = (
                from aa in list
                where Convert.ToDouble(aa) > 1
                select aa
                );


it worked for me ( notice that i used ToDouble and not Int32 because you said that the values are decimals )

Comment: So I created a new class which was exactly the same with my entity class, but the types were what they needed to be. Using a stored procedure I could get database information to a list, and use this list as I got it from entity framework. Basically, just because the guy who has 6 years of experience didn't want to store a decimal as a decimal, we are not able to write a proper code...