# Is there way to extract(refactor) several supported Linq to Entity methods to one method?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have query:

```
ctx.PrintJobs
.GroupBy(pj => pj.Department.Name)
.Select(g => new PrintJobReportItem
{
    A3SizePercentage = g.Sum(p => p.DocumentSize == "a3" ? p.TotalPhisicalPages : 0d) / g.Sum(p => p.TotalPhisicalPages) * 100,
    ...
}
```

and it works.

I have alot of those Perecentage values to count, so i tried to refactor this code to:

```
ctx.PrintJobs
.GroupBy(pj => pj.Department.Name)
.Select(g => new PrintJobReportItem
{
    A3SizePercentage = g.PercentageOf(p => p.DocumentSize == "a3"),
    ...
}
...
public static class GroupingEx
{
    public static double PercentageOf(this IGrouping<string, PrintJobItem> g, Func<PrintJobItem, bool> trueCondition)
    {
        return g.Sum(p => trueCondition(p) ? p.TotalPhisicalPages : 0d) / g.Sum(p => p.TotalPhisicalPages) * 100;
    }
}
```

But then i'm getting error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double PercentageOf...
```

I understand why i'm getting this error. 
Is there other ways to extract method group supported by Linq 2 Entity into single method? or am i stack with copy pasting same code bits?
Linq 2 Object is not an option

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in ESQL (inline function copied to multiple ESQL queries - [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373877.aspx)) and it is possible with Linq-to-entities if you are using EDMX where you can define [model defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612827/entity-framework-where-do-i-extend-the-csdl-msl/5613642#5613642). As I know code first (= no EDMX) doesn't support that - in such case you must use the approach mentioned by @Daniel where you materialize the result and use linq-to-objects to execute your method.

Comment: @qrow: Then you cannot reuse your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can first fetch the data from the database and then use your method on the local data:

```
ctx.PrintJobs.GroupBy(pj => pj.Department.Name)
             .ToList()
             .Select(g => new PrintJobReportItem
                          {
                              A3SizePercentage = 
                                  g.PercentageOf(p => p.DocumentSize == "a3"),
                              ...
                          }
```

Comment: I know that Linq to Object can handle that, but i don't want to fetch data, i would like to use Linq to Entity. I don't need results right away, i need to return IQueryable from this function, so that other functions could also add other things that would translate to sql