# Entity Framework calling database SQL string functions using Linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

If I want to call the SQL Server function `Contains(field,value)` using Linq, how can I accomplish this?

Doing something like:

```
var result = context.Documents.Where(d => d.SomeField.Contains(param)).ToList();
```

Does not use the `Contains` function in the generated SQL query. The field is a textfield with full text search enabled.

I know there should be some SQL Server string functions already mapped somewhere in the framework. Is `Contains` one of those and where can I find them?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Store Functions.  Ladislav Mrnka explains them well over at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612827/entity-framework-where-do-i-extend-the-csdl-msl/5613642#5613642).

Basically, you'll define the Contains in the EDMX and tell EF how it maps to something that SQL Server understands (note: in my example, I call this `FullTextContains` so it's not confused with the Contains method in C# - I'm not sure if this is necessary or not):

```
<Function Name="FullTextContains" ReturnType="Edm.String">
  <Parameter Name="field" Type="Edm.String" />
  <Parameter Name="value" Type="Edm.String" />
  <DefiningExpression>
    Contains(field, value)
  </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
```

Then you make a stub method in C# so you can call it via Linq:

```
public static class EdmFunctions
{
    [EdmFunction("YourModel", "FullTextContains")]
    public static string FullTextContains(string field, string value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only for L2E query.");
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to use that method in a Linq query and EF should translate it correctly.

Comment: For some reason it explodes, I've even tried to remove the parameters and hardcoded constants into the defining expression.. but it still says the generated sql is incorrect... ideas?

Comment: I expect it explodes because `CONTAINS` in SQL server is not a function. It is a predicate. Try to wrap it in custom function.