# How to: Call Model-Defined Functions in Queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to do the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

I created the function in the edmx file here just before the schema element:

```
<Function Name="YearsSince" ReturnType="Edm.Int32">
  <Parameter Name="date" Type="Edm.DateTime" />
  <DefiningExpression>
    Year(CurrentDateTime()) - Year(AppliedDate)
  </DefiningExpression>
</Function>
      </Schema>
```

Now, I want to be able to use that in a query.
I created the following code in the ApplicantPosition partial class

```
[EdmFunction("HRModel", "YearsSince")]
        public static int YearsSince(DateTime date)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
        }
```

And I am trying to do the following query

```
public class Class1
{

    public void question()
    {
        using (HREntities context = new HREntities())
        {
            // Retrieve instructors hired more than 10 years ago.
            var applicantPositions = from p in context.ApplicantPositions
                              where YearsSince((DateTime)p.AppliedDate) > 10
                              select p;

            foreach (var applicantPosition in applicantPositions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(applicantPosition.);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The YearsSince is not recognized, the MSDN tutorial does not show exactly where I need to put the functio, so that might be my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static `YearsSince` function must be defined in some class so if it is not `Class1` you must use full identification with class name to call it. Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612827/entity-framework-where-do-i-extend-the-csdl-msl/5613642#5613642).